# How to correct error at implementing vue-social-sharing, vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import SocialSharing from "vue-social-sharing";


Vue.use(SocialSharing);
```

and in another component:

```
<social-sharing url="https://vuejs.org/" title="The Progressive JavaScript Framework"
                      description="Intuitive, Fast and Composable MVVM for building interactive interfaces."
                      quote="Vue is a progressive framework for building user interfaces."
                      hashtags="vuejs,javascript,framework"
                      twitter-user="vuejs"
                      inline-template >
      <div>
        <network network="facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
        </network>
      </div>
    </social-sharing>
```

but I receive the following console errors

[image]

Guide: https://nicolasbeauvais.github.io/vue-social-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

In your `vue.config.js`, add `X-Frame-Options` header

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
     headers: {
        'X-Frame-Options': 'sameorigin'
    }
  }
}
```